# Why does ionizing radiation cause only DNA double strand breaks?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, radiation, dna-damage

It's known that ionizing radiation such as X-ray and $\gamma$-ray, cause DNA damage, specifically double strand break. Why is it so? I mean, why not single strand break, why not pyrimidine dimer?

Answer (score 7):

Ionizing radiation *does* cause single-strand breaks and other kinds of DNA lesions that are not double-strand breaks.  However, double-strand breaks are the most difficult to repair and are thus the most likely DNA damage type to result in mutation and / or cell death.  See Fig 1. from [**DNA damage response signaling pathways and targets for radiotherapy sensitization in cancer**](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41392-020-0150-x):

> [image: Figure 1 from "DNA damage response signaling pathways and targets for radiotherapy sensitization in cancer"]
> DNA damage induced by ionizing radiation. The major types of DNA damage induced by IR include base and sugar damage, single-strand breaks, double-strand breaks, clustered DNA damage, and covalent intrastrand or interstrand crosslinking